# Using Python or Model Builder to Create XY layers

Tags: python, excel, model, arcpy, arcmap

I have several columns of XY data I want to import to ArcMap.  To do it manually, I run the Excel To Table script under Conversion Tools, and then right click on the table and choose Display XY data, repeated for each pair of XY values.  I built a model that feeds the output of the "Excel to Table" script to the input of the "Make XY Event Layer" tool. The problem with that is I cannot choose any X Fields or Y Fields at the beginning without any spreadsheet imported, but when I run it, I get "No X Field Value" and "No Y Field Value" errors.  Then I built a model feeding the output of the "Excel to Table" script to a script I wrote to display the XY data.  When I run that model, I get: "ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000728: Field Latitude_decimal_degrees_ does not exist within table".  Can this process be done with Python or Model Builder, and if so, how?

Comment: What does your script look like and what do you mean by 'doesn't work the way I want it to'?

Comment: Make sure your field names actually exist, that they are valid(not strating with a number, no space) and that the Excel field format is read by ArcGIS as number. Adding a filed with a unique ID sometimes helps too.

Comment: In what version of Excel is the original data provided? Also what version of ArcMap are you using.  Depending on the version of your Excel file, ArcMap may or may not support it.  I know that in ArcMap 10.1 and later, Excel files for 2007 and later are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a single Geodatabase Table or DBF with multiple coordinate fields in it and you want to create multiple Feature Layers for each XY Coordinate Pair. If so, run this in the Python Window of ArcMap and it should do the trick:

```
import arcpy
Table= r"C:\SomeDataPath\MyTable"
# Replace 'X' and 'Y' in each sublist with the name of the respective X and Y 
# field for each coordinate pair in the table and replace 'lyrName' with the
# name you want to  give to the FeatureLayer to be created. 
# Expand with more sublists as needed
CoordinateFields = [
                    ["X", "Y", "lyrName"], 
                    ["X", "Y", "lyrName"], 
                    ["X", "Y", "lyrName"]
                   ]
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference("Name of the Projection used by coordinates")
for CoordinatePair in CoordinateFields:
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Table, 
                                      CoordinatePair[0], 
                                      CoordinatePair[1], 
                                      CoordinatePair[2],
                                      SR)
```

Enjoy!